# Using Local LLM Service That Duplicates Open AI API

Tags: llm

I have a local service running on `https://localhost:PORT/v1` that duplicates the Open AI API functionality available at `https://api.openai.com/v1`. It appears the only way to use something like [LLMSynthesize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LLMSynthesize.html) is to have an Open AI key. Is it possible to replace the base URL for any LLM calls? I presume one way to do this may be to create a [ServiceObject](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ServiceObject.html) for authentication?

Comment: Hmm... yeah, I "complained" in a relatively recent [Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2983602) that it is not clear how to plug in other LLM services in WL's LLM functions framework. In the corresponding Python and Raku packages it is easy. So, are you interested in a Python solution which you can use in Mathematica?

Comment: Yeah, in Python I'm running [vLLM](https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm) but there are a whole multitude of options for serving local LLMs. Another is [llama.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was referring to an approach closer to Mathematica's -- ["LLMFunctionObjects"](https://pypi.org/project/LLMFunctionObjects).